# Updating rows that are added dynamically using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I hope I can explain my issue clearly.

I am running a function to get values from a database using ajax, and adding each result as a row in a table. This is so the user can delete or edit any row they want. I'm adding IDs dynamically to the columns and also the edit and delete buttons which are generated. So it looks like this:
[image]

My code:

```
function getstationdata(){
var taildata1 = $('#tailnumber2').val();
var uid = $('#uid').val();
$.ajax({
    // give your form the method POST
    type: "POST",
    // give your action attribute the value ajaxadd.php
    url: "ajaxgetstationdata.php",
    data: {tailnumber:taildata1, uid:uid},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
})
.success(function(response) {
    // remove all errors
    $('input').removeClass('error').next('.errormessage').html('');

    // if there are no errors and there is a result
    if(!response.errors && response.result) {

        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
        trHTML += '<tr><td><input type="text" value="' + value[2] + '"></td><td><input type="text" class="weightinputclass"value="' + value[3] + '"></td><td><input type="text" class="arminputclass"value="' + value[4] + '"></td><td><input type="text" class="momentinputclass" value="' + value[5] + '"></td><td><button id="updatecgbtn" onclick="updatecg()"class="editbuttonclass">Edit</button></td><td><button id="deletecgbtn" class="deletebuttonclass"">Delete</button></td></tr>';

       });
          $('#mbtbody').html('');
          $('#mbtbody').html(trHTML);
          var ID = 0;
          $('.weightinputclass').each(function() {
            ID++;
            $(this).attr('id', 'weightinputboxID'+ID);
            });
          var ID = 0;
          $('.arminputclass').each(function() {
            ID++;
            $(this).attr('id', 'arminputboxID'+ID);
            });               
        var ID = 0;
          $('.momentinputclass').each(function() {
            ID++;
            $(this).attr('id', 'momentinputboxID'+ID);
            });             
        var ID = 0;
          $('.editbuttonclass').each(function() {
            ID++;
            $(this).attr('id', 'editbutton'+ID);
            });             
            var ID = 0;
          $('.deletebuttonclass').each(function() {
            ID++;
            $(this).attr('id', 'deletebutton'+ID);
            });
    } else {

        // append the error to the form
        $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
            // add error classes
            $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
        });

    }
});
}
```

The code I have when adding the info is in a form and it looks like this:

```
$('#addstations').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
    })
    .success(function(response) {
        $('input').removeClass('error').next('.errormessage').html('');
        if(!response.errors && response.result) {
            $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
            chartdata4=(tailnumber3.value)
            });
        } else {
            // append the error to the form
            $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                // add error classes
                $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')

            });
        }
    });
});
```

I searched a bit on the internet and found out that I can't add a form inside my table for each row which would have been easy to do and I can reuse my code which I use when adding new info.

So, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan: He is using Jquery, what was your point?

Comment: Also look at event delegation

Comment: @mplungjan Oh I see. So I would have to do something like "if a button with id1 is clicked, then get matching rows where their ids are column1-input1, column2-input1, then use these values and post?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan: success() is a callback...

Comment: @Bruno - yes ID must in any case be unique. But use a class and `$(this).closest("tr").find(....)` to get at the other fields

Comment: @KA_lin `success()` is not a part of the `XHR` object, so how can we use it like we would use `.done()` or `.always()` etc ?

Comment: Could you please give me some sample code for your suggestion? I am really new to all of this.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan 1.He is using jquery and uses `jqXHR` objects... How can he use `done()`? Like in the documentation: 
`var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the direction you could go

```
$('#formTable').on('click',"button" function(e){
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr"), $form = $("#addstations");
  var data = {
     passenger:$row.find("passengerClass").val(),
     weight   :$row.find("weightClass").val()
  } // no comma on the last item
  data["type"]=this.className=="deletebuttonclass"?"delete":"edit";

  $.ajax({
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    url:  $form.attr('action'),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
  })
...
```

Comment: I get it now!! I really need to learn jQuery, it looks amazing in it's simplicity! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer, i really appreciate it!

Comment: You need to test the button if it is delete or edit by the way. See update

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem is that you want to add a `form` as a child of a `table` / `tbody` element to wrap your row. You cannot do that and the browser will most likely strip the `form` tags, leaving you with nothing to `serialize`.

There are different solutions for that, for example:

1. Build the data object manually in javascript when a button on a row is clicked;
2. Use a non-form grid solution for your layout.
3. Add each row in its own table and have the form wrap that table

The third solution is a bit of a hack, I would use the first or the second myself.

Comment: I am drawn towards the 3rd option only because I am still a beginner and it is easier for me to understand. Although I suspect the drawback to that would be performance?

Comment: @Bruno No, nothing to do with performance; the column widths in your rows will possibly not be the same for different rows when they are in different tables. So it could mess up your layout although based on your screenshot that should not be a problem. And it is not really correct and semantic html :-)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you Jeroen.